# Have h1::after with one style, and .class h1::after another style?

Tags: html, css

Hey guys I hope that my title was clear enough, but I have a svg after my `<h1></h1>` as a divider using the `h1::after{}`

In one of my elements I need to change the color of the `h1::after{}`, so it would look something like `.element-class h1::after{}` i'm trying that but it doesn't work.

Is it possible to do something like this?

Comment: can you add your html too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can have more specific selectors that will overwrite existing pseudo-element styles.

```css
h1::after {
  content: ' pseudo';
  color: red;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.thing h1::after {
  content: ' other pseudo';
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<h1>Text</h1>

<div class="thing">
  <h1>Other text</h1>
</div>
```

Please note that if you are changing the SVG color, you might possibly need to change SVG contents depending on how complex your SVG is.

Comment: Ok knowing that it was possible it helped me change my css and I got it work.

Answer (score 1):

Add a class to the `h1` you want to change the color

```
<h1 class="change-color"></h1>
```

and then you can use that class

```
.change-color::after{...}
```

Let me know if that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply let me give it a try i'll let you know if it works.

Comment: If I go into inspect mode its working but the main h1::after is in front of my change-color class.

Comment: It’s not the best solution but you can add !important to the property with the change and that should work